# How to display the audio info in jList

Tags: java, swing

I would like to display the audio information to jList after I selected a lists of songs from JFileChooser. Here is what I get as far, but it throws a `NullPointerException`.

```
boolean openFile() throws FileNotFoundException{
    JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
    jfc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
    jfc.setDialogTitle("Open File");
    jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    jfc.setCurrentDirectory(new File ("."));
    jfc.setFileFilter(audiofilter);
    int result = jfc.showOpenDialog(this);
    if(result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){
        return true;
    }else if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
        File[] file = jfc.getSelectedFiles();//fFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
        String file_string = fFile.getAbsolutePath();
        for(int i=0;i<file.length;i++){
            if(file[i].isFile()){
                String[] filesInDirectory = file[i].list();
                for(int ii=0;ii<filesInDirectory.length;ii++){
                    list.addElement(filesInDirectory[ii]);
                }
            }else{
                list.addElement(file[i]);
            }
        }

        if(file_string != null){
            fTextArea.setText(file_string);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        this.jList1.setModel(list);
    }
    return true;
}
```

the error says:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at SoundsTrip.SoundBytePlaying.openFile(SoundBytePlaying.java:267)
        at SoundsTrip.SoundBytePlaying.jButton1MouseClicked(SoundBytePlaying.java:210)
        at SoundsTrip.SoundBytePlaying.access$000(SoundBytePlaying.java:43)
        at SoundsTrip.SoundBytePlaying$2.mouseClicked(SoundBytePlaying.java:135)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:253)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6270)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6032)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4247)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: There is no need to whine for help. Everyone get equally help here. Just ask the question the smart way. I cleaned the question a bit.

Comment: thanks... noted next time... :)

Comment: this is the line 267: for(int ii=0;ii<filesInDirectory.length;ii++){
                        list.addElement(filesInDirectory[ii]);
                    } thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the 1st line of the exception stacktrace.

```
at SoundsTrip.SoundBytePlaying.openFile(SoundBytePlaying.java:267)
```

It's been thrown in line 267 of class `SoundsTrip.SoundBytePlaying`, inside the `openFile()` method. Trackback it in your source code. It'll contain something like

```
someObject.doSomething();
```

A `NullPointerException` means that `someObject` is `null`. Using the period operator `.` in an attempt to access/invoke it will then throw this exception.

There are basically two ways to fix it:

1. Instantiate it beforehand so that it's not `null`.

   ```
   someObject = new SomeObject();
   someObject.doSomething();
   ```
2. Check it beforehand so that it can be bypassed when it's `null`.

   ```
   if (someObject != null) {
       someObject.doSomething();
   }
   ```

Which to choose depends on the sole functional requirement.

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367) state that package names should preferably be written in all lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this line:

```
if(file[i].isFile()){
       String[] filesInDirectory = file[i].list();
...
```

change it to:

```
if(!file[i].isFile()){
    String[] filesInDirectory = file[i].list();
```

You can populate filesInDirectory only if this file[i] is a directory (meaning it is not a file).

Comment: Wow, thank you sir, it Worked. i wish i could already vote and vote this as the answer. but i can't because my reputation is below 15 as the requirements to allow me. anyways thank you sir draganstankovic.... :)

Comment: No problem. This 'sir' sounds so 'mighty' didn't used to it. Maybe I can try to convince my wife to call me this way and if I survive that I'll tell ya' :) Good luck with your studies!